# Correct Shadow Pass in Internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, light, render-passes

I'm trying to extract a shadow pass in internal but it isn't looking like expected.

This is what the render looks like:
[image]

But the shadow pass looks like this: 
[image]

It brutally cuts off the side of the face and the floor, but the main render has a much smoother transition on the face and more easily seen, the floor. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using a spotlamp?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like this to work with any sort of light.

Comment: I'm just wondering if BI soft shadows are rendered in the shadow pass

Comment: If they aren't I'd enjoy being able to combine them somehow with all the other shadows.

Comment: @meed96 sorry, I was momentarily confused. I think they are different enough to be separate tags.

Comment: @David Alrighty, wasn't sure, never created tags before :D